# Difference between sample and sequence in Law of Large Numbers

Tags: sample, convergence, law-of-large-numbers

I'm comparing the Chebychev (Weak) Law of Large Numbers (LLN) to the Kolmogorov (Strong) LLN in an econometric textbook and both definitions start off differently. The Chebychev LLN begins with

If $x_i, i = 1, . . . , n$ is a sample of of observations such that . . .

while the Kolmogorov LLN begins with

If $x_i, i = 1, . . . , n$ is a sequence of independently distributed random variable such that . . .

I know they refer to convergence in probability and convergence almost surely respectively but what is the significance of using a sample in one and a sequence in the other? Is it harder to prove convergence in a sequence as opposed to a sample?